# grep doesn't take getopts

Tags: bash, grep, eval, getopts

There is a directory:

```
.
├── file4.txt
├── file5.yml
├── txt
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
└── yml
└── file6.yml
```

Some files contain a word `hello`:

```
>> grep -r 'hello' .

  ./file4.txt:hello
  ./yml/file6.yml:hello
  ./txt/file1.txt:hello
  ./txt/file2.txt:hello
  ./file5.yml:hello
```

And now I want to write a script, which would search for `hello` in different locations and files, i.e.:

```
$ grep -EHori --exclude-dir={txt,yml} --include="*.txt" 'hello' .
  ./file4.txt:hello
$ grep -EHori --exclude-dir={txt,yml} --include="*.yml" 'hello' .
  ./file5.yml:hello
$ grep -EHori --exclude-dir={yml} --include="*.yml" 'hello' .
  ./yml/file6.yml:hello
  ./file5.yml:hello
$ grep -EHori --exclude-dir={txt} --include="*.yml" 'hello' .
  ./yml/file6.yml:hello
  ./file5.yml:hello
$ grep -EHori --exclude-dir={txt} --include="*.txt" 'hello' .
  ./file4.txt:hello
  ./txt/file1.txt:hello
  ./txt/file2.txt:hello
```

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

exclude_path="txt"
file_types="*.txt"
include_path="./"
check_path="./"

while getopts ":e:t:i:p" opt; do
    case $opt in
         e)
            exclude_path="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
         t)
            file_types="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
         i)
            include_path="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
         p)
            check_path="${OPTARG}"
    esac
done

result=$(grep -EHori --exclude-dir=$exclude_path \
    --include=$file_types 'hello' "$check_path")
echo $result
```

But, it doesn't work with multiple values for `exclude_path` and `include_path` , i.e.:

`grep -r --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3} --include={type1,type2,type3} keyword /path/to/search`

Also if I use `-p`, grep complains `No such file`.

```
$ ./grep.sh
  ./file4.txt:hello
$ ./grep.sh -t *.yml
  ./file5.yml:hello
$ ./grep.sh -p yml -t *.yml
  grep: : No such file or directory
$ ./grep.sh -t *txt,*.yml
```

I do need to save the `result` as a variable since I work with it further. I think I should used `eval` wtih `grep` and escape variables, but I'm not sure.

Comment: show the exact command which you invokes your script.

Comment: @pynexj right, I added it to the question.

Comment: For complex path searches I would tend to use `grep` as the command with `find` to do the file selection.

Comment: @GemTaylor, I don't look for files actually, but for 'hello' or any other 'keyword'.

Comment: You are wanting to use `-exclude-dir=$exclude_path --include=$file_types` to select the files you want. I'm suggesting `find` is a better tool to make those selections, then have `find` launch the `grep` command that you want.

Comment: @GemTaylor, I don't know how many directories a user will want to exclude/include, how many file types. Looking at `find`'s syntax it looks way more complicated than grep. I also think that `find` + `grep` will be slower. But I can be wrong. Can you give an example of find+grep solution, maybe?

Comment: The GNU guys REALLY messed up by giving grep options to recursively find files. There's a perfectly good UNIX tool for doing that with a perfectly obvious and appropriate name - `find`. Right now your grep command is a hodge-podge of options to find files and options to find text within files. Keep each functionality separate and simple as UNIX intends and use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to within each file **G**lobally search for text matching a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the result (**G/RE/P**) Forget you ever heard of any grep options for recursively finding files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your getopt statement:

```
while getopts ":e:t:i:p" opt; do
```

should be

```
while getopts ":e:t:i:p:" opt; do
```

without the last `:` `p` doesn't take any argument, so when you typed `-p yml` it executed `grep ... ''` cause `check_path=""` cause OPTARG was empty for `p`:

```
$ bash -x ./grep.sh -p yml -t '*.yml'
...
++ grep -EHori --exclude-dir=txt '--include=*.txt' hello ''
grep: : No such file or directory
...
```

The fixed script outputs:

```
$ ./grep.sh -p yml -t '*.yml'
yml/file6.yml:hello
```

Side note: Remember to properly enclose your arguments, typing `./grep.sh -p yml -t *.yml` will execute `./grep.sh -p yml -t file5.yml` cause `*` gets expanded by bash. Probably you meant to enclose it in `'`, otherwise `./grep.sh -p yml -t *.yml` returns only empty line (from the `echo`), because `file5.yml` is not inside `yml` directory.

Comment: right! thank you. Stupid typo =). But what about `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3} --include={type1,type2,type3}` part? `./grep.sh -t '*.yml,*.txt'`, or `./grep.sh -t "\*.yml,\*.txt"` don't work.

Comment: well, `*.yml,*.txt` matches files named `*.yml,*.txt`, not files named `*.yml` or `*.txt`. You need to `./grep.sh -t '*[.yml|.txt]'`, you can read about glob [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm).

Comment: It worked in shell, because of expansion: `string{a,b,c}` gets expanded by bash to `stringa stringb stringc`, so when you typed `grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}` it executed `grep --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2`. Bash does not expand variable when passing through variable names, I mean smth like `a="--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}"; grep "$a"` will not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it works with 
`eval grep -EHori --exclude-dir={$exclude_path} \
        --include={$file_types} 'hello' "$check_path"`